# Python : mock an attribute or mock the whole class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to mock the Popen instance in the following business code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = process.communicate()[0]
if process.returncode != 0:
```

This is my test code setup:

```
@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen.returncode')
@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen.communicate')
def testCommandExecutesCommunicate(self, mock_popen_communicate, mock_popen_returncode):
```

I have also tried:

```
@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen.returncode')
@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen.communicate')
def testCommandExecutesCommunicate(self, mock_popen_communicate, mock_popen_returncode):
```

In both situations, I get an error with `returncode` mocking

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1297, in patched
    arg = patching.__enter__()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1369, in __enter__
    original, local = self.get_original()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock/mock.py", line 1343, in get_original
    "%s does not have the attribute %r" % (target, name)
AttributeError: <class 'subprocess.Popen'> does not have the attribute 'returncode'
```

How should I mock out Popen?  Should I mock out the Popen class somehow? Or am I on the right track by mocking out the methods + attributes?

Comment: You don't mock things where they come from, you mock them where they're used. In this case you presumably `import subprocess`, so start with something like `@mock.patch('my.module.subprocess')`.

Comment: ok. assuming the business code is in a class called shellCommand, and this is in a directory called lib.  Would I do: @mock.patch('lib.shellCommand.subprocess.Popen.returncode')

Comment: I moved the business logic to the test class to simplify the imports, and used this: 
    @mock.patch('tests.test_commandShell.subprocess.Popen.returncode')

and I ended up getting the same error as before.

Answer (score 1):

> `AttributeError:  does not have the attribute 'returncode'

Look at code at `subprocess.py`,

```
class Popen():
    def __init__(self, ....):
        self.returncode = None
```

The attribute `returncode` is set by `__init__` and later updated by `communicate()` etc, the class attribute `returncode` is not mock friendly and causing errors

> why mockp.communicate() mockp.communicate.return_value = '123'

`mockp.communicate` or with `()`,  is the same as `mockp.communicate = mock.Mock()`, a way to create a new mock object for function `communicate`

`mock.communicate.return_value = list([2, 3])` is to set the return_value of the mocked function.

> solution: I am not totally happy with the solution, but I tend to think mock the whole class 'Popen()` is the way to go for the unittests.

For unittest, just mock the whole class, mock `subprocess.Popen` and set `returncode` and `communicate()` and set `return_value`, e.g.

`remove_file.py`

```
def do_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    exit_code = process.communicate()[0]
    return exit_code
```

`test_remove_file.py`

```
class TestDoCmd(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('remove_file.subprocess.Popen')
    def test_do_cmd(self, mockp):
        # add function
        mockp.returncode.return_value = 'abc'
        mockp.communicate()
        mockp.communicate.return_value = '123'
        file = '/tmp/none.txt'
        remove_file.do_cmd('rm -f {}'.format(file))
        mockp.assert_called_with('rm -f /tmp/none.txt', shell=True, stdout=-1)
```

Comment: I didn't understand why you did this: 
mockp.communicate()
mockp.communicate.return_value = '123'

Comment: @MedicineMan, `mockp` is `mock.Mock()`, `mockp.communicate()` is the same as `mockp.communicate = mock.Mock()`, which created another mock for the function. the return_value the function `communicate()` should be a list.